# How can I mitigate brush strokes in ceiling paint?

Tags: ceiling

So I’ve painted a ceiling for a lady whose husband had covered the ceiling in satin, with a brush. I mean the entire ceiling.

3 coats of satin later and all the brush strokes are still very visible. Have I any other way to solve this apart from sand the entire space and repaint?

[image]

Comment: And what did it look like before you started? Perhaps the lady doesn't mind brush stroke marks, given the history here.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that when you write "covered the ceiling in satin" you're actually referring to a satin sheen paint, and not the actual fabric satin?

Comment: No offense to her ceiling, but that’s never going to look nice. (Unless you skim and sand, but that’s a whole different job.) I’d try one more coat with a thick nap roller to get as much orange peel as possible and then call it quits. Even if you don’t get paid, you’ll have learned a lesson.

Comment: Don't use satin, use flat?

Comment: One technique to try and minimize the look is to have your brush strokes parallel to the direction of incoming light rather than perpendicular.

Comment: That sounds good, @Matthew, but doesn't that mean one has to paint radially from the center of the light fixture out?

Comment: @FreeMan Typically ceiling lights will not have an extremely shallow angle of light, as light from the sun can be from a 0 degree angle and upwards, which can cast shadows from ridges resulting from brushstrokes.

Answer (score 1):

Try again with a roller? That will avoid most brush strokes, though there may be other texture effects.

Comment: FYI: `This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.` The system didn't like your answer, though it looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: This is why it flags for review rather than responding entirely automatically. Sometimes a terse answer really is all that's needed to express the idea.

Comment: Agreed. Just letting you know what the system thought of you. Oh, yeah, you got a +1 on this during the review process.

Comment: That's fine. The system doesn't want to know what I sometimes think of it... <grin/>

Answer (score 0):

You don't sand interior wall or ceiling surfaces that have been painted. Latex just doesn't sand well.

If anything, you'd skim it with drywall topping compound and sand *that* lightly as needed. You could also spray texture over it.